# A is bounded iff the neighborhood contains A

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $M$ be a metric space with metric $d$, then the diameter of $A \subset M$ is the value $diam(A) = sup \{\ d(a,b) : a,b \in A\}$, we say that $A$ is bounded if $diam(A) < \infty$.

With this I'm trying to prove that $A$ is bounded if and only if there is a point $a_0 \in A$ and $r>0$ such that $A \subset V_r(a_0)$.

Can someone help me prove this please? Thanks.

Comment: Neighborhood (or ball) of radius r.

Comment: It is a r-neighborhood of a0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't prove this for you, but I'll throw you a few hints:

**Hint 1:** Knowing the definition of the diameter of $A$, what happens if we fix a point $x\in A$ and consider the neighborhood of "radius" $diam(A)$ about $x$?

**Hint 2:** For the converse, given the existence of such an $r>0$, which is finite, what can you say about the diameter of the set $A$? Must it too be finite?

Comment: I was going to give an answer but this is more instructive.

Comment: I'm glad you think so: hopefully the OP will be able to learn from it.